# Can DLC be shared along with games with family sharing?

Tags: steam, steam-family-sharing

Using Steam's Family Sharing feature, can you share DLC as well as games?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can share DLC with Steam Family Sharing.

***However***, DLC will *not* be shared if the "guest" (as opposed to the lender) also owns the game:

> *Who owns and can access the DLC and in-game content associated with a shared title?*
>
> A guest will have access to the lender's DLC, but only if the guest doesn't also own the base game. Guests may not purchase DLC for a base game they don't own. Any player may purchase, trade, earn, or otherwise acquire in-game content while playing a game, but in-game items cannot be shared between accounts. These items remain the property of the account that purchased or acquired them, whether borrowing or lending the base game.

http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing